# How to call java script function from dynamic component in apex

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am getting below error :

> Value assigned to expression field is not valid for `<apex:commandButton oncomplete>`

I am calling javascript function on `'oncomplete'`.

```
 Component.Apex.commandButton commandbuttonNext = new  Component.Apex.commandButton();
 commandbuttonNext.expressions.action = '{!next}';
 commandbuttonNext.expressions.oncomplete = 'loadResponsiveTable();';
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you are providing to `oncomplete` is not an expression, but a static value. So you should avoid using `expressions` property of commandButton and instead provide the `oncomplete` value directly to `commandButton` like this.

```
commandbuttonNext.oncomplete = 'loadResponsiveTable();';
```